# use a udf in vba excel for multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

a user defined function I use in excel

```
Function Hex2RGB(hex As String) As String

    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 5, 2))

  Debug.Print RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    Hex2RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

End Function
```

I have a worksheet with a 10 times 10 matrix for which this function would need to be used for every cell in the range. There has to be some way that I don't have to click on each cell and enter =Hex2RGB("value") manually?
when I write value I am referring to something like OD62A2....which is the colour than to be transformed in excel format

Comment: Where do you store hex values? If you don't store them somewhere in the workbook, there is unfortunately no other way (unless you insert those hex codes based on some logic such as value +1)

Comment: the hex values are stored in the worksheet ( in the 10 times 10 matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Use a range parameter instead of value as below. Set the function manually to the first cell (e.g. left upper cell in the matrix) then copy and paste it across the matrix - the range will change

```
Public Function Hex2RGB(r As Range) As String
    Dim hex As String: r.Value
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 5, 2))

  Debug.Print RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    Hex2RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

End Function
```

Comment: if I try this I get a value! error. In the first cell I typed Hex2RGB("value"). How do I have to enter it?

Comment: instead of typing "value" you target a cell as visible from function ...(r as Range)

Comment: I am quite new to vba....how do I do that? do i highlight all cells and then just enter in the function bar in excel =Hex2RGB?

Comment: i already set the function manually to the first cell in the top left with =Hex2RGB("value") but then I get an value! error.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**  Add the following macro.  This macro will iterate over the cells in the selected range, and replace them with a formula based on its own value, which I think is what you are trying to do.

```
Sub GetHexValues()
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim cl as Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
    For each cl in rng.Cells
        cl.Formula = "=Hex2RGB(" & Chr(34) & cl.Value & Chr(34) & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

**Step 2** Make sure your function is:

```
Public Function Hex2RGB(hex) As String
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 5, 2))

    Debug.Print RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    Hex2RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

End Function
```

**Step 3:** *Select* the matrix range.  (NB: Normally I recommend not using `Select` but as a means of user-input it is OK to do that here, I think.)

There is generally speaking, no way to use a UDF worksheet function to manipulate a range of cells in the manner you're describing. UDF's can generally not alter many properties and values of cells/ranges *except* the cell that is calling the function. This is to avoid circular reference/etc. (there are workarounds to this limitation, but generally accepted rule is to use Subroutines to manipulate the worksheet objects).

Comment: hello...that is a nice solution when I copy your code and run the macro after selection the range I get error 1004 objectdefind err . it is in the line cl.Formula= line. I set the function before the macro so it is not missing....

Comment: Looks like I forgot a quotation mark at the end of that line. I will revise the answer.

Comment: sorry but I dont see a difference...I thought 4 quot marks should be alright?

Comment: I added a quotation mark at the end which was previously omitted, but that still doesn't work. See updated answer now.

Comment: could you tell me what the  CH(34) does?

Comment: Yes, `Chr` is a vba function ([info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465(v=office.15).aspx)). It returns a string, in this case `34` is the code for quotation mark `"`.  I use this sometimes because quotes are *also* what define string literals and I always forget how to properly escape them. I think without using `Chr` you could do `"=Hex2RGB(""" & cl.Value """)"`.  If you're wondering why the alternative requires so many quote marks, well, that's why I use `Chr(34)` inside strings because I can never remember how many quotes are needed :)